# PHP SQL group by user

Tags: php, mysql, grouping

I have a game where I'm saving each point to each player. 
Now I want to build a highscore where it lists the players with the best scores. but I want only the highest score per player visible.

Ex:

```
David 38 points
Elin 25 points
Kelly 3 points
```

And not:

```
David 38 points
David 35 points
Elin 25 points
Elin 23 points
Elin 20 points
etc etc
```

My code today:

```
$sql="select userID, poang from floppy ORDER BY poang DESC  LIMIT 10"; 
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()."<br />".$sql); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row[userID]." ".$row['poang']." points<br />";
}
```

Anyone know how to do?

Comment: what is column name for "David, Elin"?

Comment: `SUM` OR `MAX` (depends on what you want) + `GROUP BY`

Comment: You got `group by` in your question, but not in your query, did you try something like `select userID, poang FROM floppy ORDER BY poang DESC GROUP BY userID LIMIT 10` ?

Comment: @Jurik Your query won't work, as poang is not in the group by clause

Comment: It will always take the first occurrence (row) when you group by and when you first order by highest points, you should get wanted result. But your answer looks still better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 10 userID, MAX(poang) from floppy GROUP BY userID ORDER BY MAX(poang) DESC
```

Comment: Hi,

With this code:
    $sql ="SELECT TOP 10 userID, MAX(poang) from floppy GROUP BY userID ORDER BY MAX(poang) DESC";

i got this error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '10 userID, MAX(poang) from floppy GROUP BY userID ORDER BY MAX(poang) DESC' at line 1

Comment: You didn't specify it was mysql, TOP is TRANSACT SQL as I assumed it was SQL Server. Remove TOP 10 and add LIMIT 10 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use Group By For taking only one & max() for maximum value

Comment: Hi, i get this:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Group By userID' at line 1
select userID, poang from floppy ORDER BY MAX(poang) DESC LIMIT 10 Group By userID